# Laravel constrain eager loading - apply limit if relationship column != 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Am building a system that works similar to the popular flashcard software called "Anki" and am trying to eager load some answers that belong to a user study, but with some modifications.

Model relationships

- `User` has many `Study`
- `Study` has many `Answer`

Here is the code snippet. **(Take a look at the second section below)**

```php
$user_query = User::with([
    'studies.answers' => function ( $query_answer ) use ( $args ) {
        $query_answer
            ->where( 'grade', '=', 'hold' )
            ->groupBy( 'card_id' )
            ->orderByDesc( 'id' );

            if ( $args['no_date_limit'] ) {
                $query_answer = $query_answer->where( 'next_due_at', '>', $args['start_date'] );
            } else {
                $query_answer = $query_answer->whereBetween( 'next_due_at', [ $args['start_date'], $args['end_date'] ] );
            }

            if ( ! empty( $args['card_ids_in'] ) ) {
                $query_answer = $query_answer->whereIn( 'card_id', $args['card_ids_in'] );
            }
            if ( ! empty( $args['card_ids_not_in'] ) ) {
                $query_answer = $query_answer->whereNotIn( 'card_id', $args['card_ids_not_in'] );
            }
```

**Below, I want to apply the limit if `study.answer_all_on_hold`  `($study_all_on_hold)`  != 1
And also read the `$no_on_hold` value from `study.no_on_hold`**

```php
            // Here, I want to apply the limit ($study_all_on_hold ) if study.answer_all_on_hold != 1
            if ( ! $study_all_on_hold ) {
                // And also read the $no_on_hold value from study.no_on_hold
                $query_answer = $query_answer->limit( $no_on_hold );
            }
        },
    ])
    ->where( 'ID', '=', $user_id );
```

As you can see am trying to apply the limit from the column value of the study.
Is this currently possible ?

### Edit

I've figured out how to add the limit by reading the value of the column from study `study.no_on_hold`. What is remaining is a way to apply that limit only when `study.answer_all_on_hold` is != 1

```
//if ( ! $study_all_on_hold ) {
            $query_answer = $query_answer->limit( 'study.no_on_hold' );
//  }
```

Comment: Probably not in a single query. You can definitely map over the resulting collection to get the format you desire though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I really need to eager load the answers with all those conditions applied. I've tried loading it separately, while looping through the studies but lots of queries are run, which is why I sorted for eager loading.

Comment: There's no way to do this, even in raw SQL. Also you should look into conditional query clauses using `when()` method, it will make your code much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, Eloquent is doing 3 queries:

1. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $user_id`
2. `SELECT * FROM studies WHERE user_id IN (all users.id from query 1)`
3. `SELECT * FROM answers WHERE study_id IN (all studies.id FROM query 2)`

Then, it's grouping all the results into the resulting `Collection`. You can't put a `LIMIT` on query 3 because of the way Eloquent works.

I think you could get the results you want by applying some [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections).

```php
$user_query = User::...get();

$user_query = $user_query->each(function ($user) {
    $user->studies->transform(function ($study) {
        if ($study->answer_all_on_hold != 1) {
            $study->answers = $study->answers->take($study->no_on_hold)->values();
            return $study;
        } else {
            return $study;
        }
    });
});
```

This won't alter the query (so you'll still query every answer), and will even cause some extra overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't really want to make any looping as there will be many studies as users start to use the system. Also calling $user->studies will execute another query, and so will $study->answers (which will execute for each study). Isn't it?

Comment: I've figured out how to apply the limits by doing $query_answer = $query_answer->limit( 'study.no_on_hold' ); . The only thing remaining is how to apply that limit only when study.answer_all_on_hold is =1 (when it is true)

Comment: Doing `$query_answer->limit('study.no_on_hold')` will have an effect on every answer. not just the ones belonging to a particular `Study`.

Comment: To see what I mean, try putting `limit(1)` and you'll see you'll have a single answer across 3 studies, even if all studies had at least one answer.

Comment: Doing `$query_answer->limit('study.no_on_hold')` limits the number of answers I will read for each `Study` to the value of each `study.no_on_hold`, and that's what I need. That is why I couldn't use a hard value for the limit, like `limit(1)`. It currently serves me well, only that I need to apply that limit only when the column value of `study.answer_all_on_hold`  for each study is `!= 1`